# how to make a get request from angular in order to pass a @RequestBody in spring boot controller

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, post, get, httpclient

I am developping an angular spring boot application. My objective is to receive in my spring controller a @RequestBody param. Reading posts on internet, I only found POST request that send @RequestBody params, while, in my case it is a GET request.
However, I hold on a POST controller method. Here is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/produitimmobilier/all/{pageSize}/{page}",
method = RequestMethod.POST,
produces = {"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
consumes = {"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody List<ProduitImmobilierDTO> findAll(@PathVariable("pageSize") int pageSize, @PathVariable("page") int page, @RequestBody Search search){
    logger.info(search.toString());
    return produitImmobilierService.findAll(pageSize, page);
}
```

I tried to contain to a post request on angular side like the following

```
  getListProduitImmobilierDTO(pagesize: number, page: number, search: Search): Observable<ProduitImmobilierDTO[]> {
    const headerDict = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Accept-Charset': 'charset=UTF-8',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
    };

    const requestOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders(headerDict)
    };
    return this.http.post<Search>('/api/produitimmobilier/all/' + pagesize + '/' + page, search, requestOptions).pipe(map((jsonArray: any) =>jsonArray.map((jsonItem) => ProduitImmobilierDTO.fromJson(jsonItem))));
  }
```

and I got this error

```
Error:  occured while trying to proxy to: localhost:4200/api/produitimmobilier/all/5/1
Message: Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/produitimmobilier/all/5/1: 504 Gateway Timeout
```

As I understood, I cannot put post<Search> with a Search object parameter and receive  a   Observable<ProduitImmobilierDTO[]> response. I found absolutely nothing on internet. Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I misunderstood the question and may be wrong, but you are making a request to the server at the angular address of the application. This can be seen in the error text `localhost:4200/api`. Try to contact the server work address. For example:

`return this.http.post<Search>('http:localhost:8080/api/produitimmobilier/all/' + pagesize + '/' + page, search, requestOptions).pipe(map((jsonArray: any) =>jsonArray.map((jsonItem) => ProduitImmobilierDTO.fromJson(jsonItem))));`

Instead of `http://localhost:8080` you need to insert the address of your server